# Should input sanitisation also be considered in Ballerina SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, ballerina

I'm currently working with parameterised queries in Ballerina.

```
int id = 10;
int age = 12;
sql:ParameterizedQuery query = `SELECT * FROM students WHERE id < ${id} AND age > ${age}`;
```

I want to ensure the security of my application. I'm wondering whether it's necessary to sanitise all the inputs to these queries as an additional layer of security when using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterized query in SQL library is transformed into a prepared statement by the SQL library before calling the database driver for that particular database. As far as I know this transformation from Parameterized query into a prepared SQL statement is done for MySQL in JBallerina[1][2][3]. This could be different for other implementations. So for MySQL I would say you really don't have to worry about SQL injection attacks with properly formed parameterized query.

[1] - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-mysql/blob/master/ballerina/client.bal#L59

[2] - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-mysql/blob/master/native/src/main/java/io/ballerina/stdlib/mysql/nativeimpl/QueryProcessor.java#L37

[3] - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-sql/blob/master/native/src/main/java/io/ballerina/stdlib/sql/nativeimpl/QueryProcessor.java#L80